Flink SQL Hints in Confluent Flink Window Query
How do I use hints in a windowing query on Confluent Flink?
Example of a hint:
/*+ OPTIONS('scan.startup.mode'='latest-offset') */

I would like to use it in a query like below:
INSERT INTO topic2(id, name, avgValue)
SELECT id, name, AVG(value) as avgValue
FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE topic1, DESCRIPTOR(messageTimestamp), INTERVAL '30' SECONDS))
GROUP BY window_start, window_end, id, name;


In order to do this, the TABLE topic syntax will need to be replaced with a SELECT query.  (Note that the query does need to be in parentheses.)
This should do it:
INSERT INTO topic2(id, name, avgValue)
SELECT id, name, AVG(value) as avgValue
FROM TABLE(
  TUMBLE(
    (SELECT * FROM topic1 /*+ OPTIONS('scan.startup.mode'='latest-offset') */), 
    DESCRIPTOR(messageTimestamp), 
    INTERVAL '30' SECONDS
  ))
GROUP BY window_start, window_end, id, name;

Further similar queries may need to list the DESCRIPTOR (in the case that it is a metadata virtual column like $rowtime); that doesn't appear to be necessary here.

Nice! I had given up trying to solve this.
